# render erb from database into view problem please help!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, erb

i am saving some erb in my database and rendering it in the view like this:

```
erb = ERB.new(content)
render :text => erb.result
```

I am getting errors when trying render erb that has the image_tag in the erb saved in the database.  The error is :

```
undefined method `image_tag' for main:Object
```

Anyone help on this ?  i also get the error with the stylesheet_link_tag ?

Thank alot 
rick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you would need to pass the optional binding parameter to the ERB::render method. This effectively provides the local variables in the scope of the ERB template. In other words the binding needs to provide the image_tag variable to the template.

I don't know what 'content' is in your case but the following will pass the binding from the 'parent' view assuming that @obj.image_tag is visible from that view:

```
<%= ERB.new("image tag - \<\%= @obj.image_tag \%\>").result(binding) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't helper in your controller. You need include all Helper do you use.

Comment: i am not doing this from the controller.  I am doing this in side a view.   any ideas?